# как сделать кнопку в textarea

Tags: css, html5

как сделать кнопку в теге textarea вот как на примере,не обязательно с галочкой просто кнопку и хотелось бы чтобы текст который там будет писаться не заходил под кнопку.[image: кнопка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По возможности избегайте наложений на поля ввода, особенно на текстовые области - вы неизбежно отъедаете пространство для ввода и ухудшаете UX. Лучше располагать все управляющие кнопки сбоку или снизу от полей ввода.

Верстка в вашей ситуации в общем виде будет такая:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <textarea class="input"></textarea>
  <button class="input-addon">Сохранить</button>
</div>
```

Кнопку расположите абсолютно, снизу справа с небольшим отступом, и с фиксированной высотой/шириной.

```
.input-group .input-addon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

А у текстовой области задайте либо нижний паддинг, либо правый:

```
.input-group .input {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 70px;
}
```

В этом случае вы не сможете вводить текст по всему правому или по всему нижнему краю, и он не будет залезать под кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
}

#txt {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FC913A 0%, #FF4E50 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    padding: 10px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#c0392b;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#c0392b;}/* Firefox 19+ */
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#c0392b;}/* Firefox 18- */
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#c0392b;}

:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent}
```

```html
<div>
    <textarea name="" id="txt" placeholder="&#8250; Message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button>Сохранить</button>
</div>
```